# Common difference between terms of the arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In an finite arithmetic progression: $S_5=55$, sum of the last five terms is 215 and total sum is $S_n=351$ . What is  common difference between terms of the arithmetic progression? Why?

Comment: See what you can do with these resulting equations ($d$=difference, $a$=first term, $n$=no. of terms):
$$\begin{align}
S_5=55 &\implies \frac{5}{2}\left(2a+4d\right)\\
\\
S_n=351 &\implies\frac{n}{2}\left(2a+(n-1)d\right)\\
\\
215=\left(a+(n-1)d\right)+\left(a+(n-2)d\right)+&\cdots+\left(a+(n-5)d\right)=5(a+dn-3d)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $a_1$ be the first term and $a_n$ the last term, and let $d$ be the common difference.

- Show that the sum of the first five terms is $5a_1+10d$, and conclude that $a_1+2d=11$.
- Show that the sum of the last five terms is $5a_n-10d$, and conclude that $a_n-2d=43$.
- What is $a_1+a_n$?
- Use the fact that $S_n=\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}2$ to find $n$.
- Then use the fact that $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ to get an equation in the unknowns $a_1$ and $d$ that you can pair with $a_1+2d=11$ to solve for $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Solve the system
$$S_5=\frac{5}{2}(2a_1+4d)=55$$
$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a_1+(n-1)d)=351$$
$$5a_1+(5n-15)d=215$$